How to do multiple inputs in Python
I am new to learning python.
I want to give the user the option to add multiple inputs for time.
Then my equation solves it but I can't figure it out.
Here's the code I have written
python3
print("RC Circuit Calculator")
Resistance = float(input("Resistance (R) : "))
Capacitance = float(input("Capacitance (C) : "))
Voltage_Source = float(input("Source Voltage (V) : "))
t = np.array(input("Time Intervals : ").split())
V_c = Voltage_Source*(1 - np.exp(-t/(Resistance*Capacitance)))
print(V_c)


Some ideas of how to get multiple inputs https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python/#
